# How to find a document in Mongoid by ID without the model?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Is there a way to use Mongoid to find a document by id, without knowing which model it is?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as how Mongoid is an ODM (Object-Document-Mapper) framework for MongoDB in Ruby, I do not believe this is possible. Knowing the model is a crucial component of Mongoid so that it can appropriately translate between your objects in code and the document representation of the data within MongoDB.

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Mongoid is very very cool and robust (love the indexing & performance features provided), I'm jealous you get to work with it! haha; hope you enjoy!! :0)

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround is to iterate over all the collections, and execute the find method for all of them.
(It can have an impact on performance depending on the number and size of the collections.)

This code assumes, that the naming of the collections follows the convention: the name of the model with lower case in plural form.

```
def self.find_with_id_in_all_collections(id)
  all_collections = Mongoid.default_session.collections
  all_models = all_collections.collect{|col| col.name.singularize.camelize}
  all_models.each {|model|
    begin
      found_with_id = eval(model  + ".find(id)")
      return found_with_id
    rescue Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound
     #nothing to do: keep on searching in the other collections
    end
  }
  # if no such ID has been found in any of the collections:
  raise "No document with the ID #{id} found in any of the following collections: #{all_collections}} resp. models: #{all_models}"
end
```

Comment: This approach might actually work, because each collection should have an index on `id`.